# Custom Datatable Type CSS inside the cell

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am trying to create a Datatable extension with custom columns that display a colored dot with different colors depending on case status. I am able to pass down a class name to the html component that I need.
The problem is that the css class is not found.
I have a .css with the datatableExtension name in the same folder.
I also have a .css with the customType.
Neither works and css is not loaded.
How do I import the css into the datatable component ?
I managed to pass inline css to the component but I am looking for a proper solution.

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/391905/edit) the question and add the key parts of the code (HTML and Javascript) that you currently use for the  custom DataType and Lightning-Datatable?

Comment: The specifics does matter. You have to show some effort and then people can answer specific questions you may have. Your question should show, what you have tried so far (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., exact error text) and where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok, your answer explains that it should work in the general case and my code was correct. This is what I needed to know. At this point the specifics start to matter. Please understand that I can't just post code from working projects .... and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Salesforce `lightning-datatable` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) custom CSS classes are not currently supported.

> Custom classes are currently not supported. To apply custom styling on your datatable cells, create a custom data type and then apply your custom CSS classes.

So, to achieve this functionality we need to build a [Custom Data Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types). I have used slds icon [custom12](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/) to show a color dot in the cell.

**Custom Data Type Component - customTypeCaseStatus**

*customTypeCaseStatus.html*

```
<template>
    <lightning-icon class={iconClass} icon-name="custom:custom12"></lightning-icon>
</template>
```

*customTypeCaseStatus.js*

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
export default class CustomTypeCaseStatus extends LightningElement {
    baseIconClass = "baseIcon";
    inputIconClass;
    @api caseStatus = "default";
    get iconClass() {
        this.inputIconClass = `${this.caseStatus}Icon`;
        return `${this.baseIconClass} ${this.inputIconClass}`;
    }
}
```

*customTypeCaseStatus.css*

```
.baseIcon{
    --slds-c-icon-color-background: white;
}
.defaultIcon {
    --slds-c-icon-color-foreground: gray;
}
.greenIcon {
    --slds-c-icon-color-foreground: green;
}
.redIcon {
    --slds-c-icon-color-foreground: red;
}
.blueIcon {
    --slds-c-icon-color-foreground: blue;
}
.orangeIcon {
    --slds-c-icon-color-foreground: orange;
}
```

**Custom Datatable Component - customLightningDatatable**

*customLightningDatatable.html*

```
<template>
</template>
```

*customLightningDatatable.js*

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import customCaseTemplate from './customType.html';
export default class CustomLightningDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        customTypeCaseStatus: {
            template: customCaseTemplate,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['caseStatus'],
        }
    };
}
```

**Final Demo Component - datatableCustomDatatypeDemo**

*datatableCustomDatatypeDemo.html*

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <c-custom-lightning-datatable key-field="id" columns={columns} data={data} hide-checkbox-column>
        </c-custom-lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

*datatableCustomDatatypeDemo.js*

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name',
    },
    {
        label: 'Status',
        type: 'customTypeCaseStatus',
        typeAttributes: {
            caseStatus: { fieldName: 'caseStatus' }
        },
        cellAttributes: { alignment: 'center' }
    }
];
export default class DatatableCustomDatatype extends LightningElement {

    columns = columns;
    data = [
        {
            Id: 1, Name: 'Case1', caseStatus:'red'
        },
        {
            Id: 2, Name: 'Case2', caseStatus:'green'
        },
        {
            Id: 3, Name: 'Case3', caseStatus:'blue'
        },
        {
            Id: 4, Name: 'Case4', caseStatus:'orange'
        }
    ]    
}
```

*Screenshot of the final demo component*

[image]

Comment: customTypeCaseStatus.css - this doesn't apply in my case - css doesn't show as if the file doesn't exist. Any idea if it is not working specifically in LWR(experience cloud) or I should ask Salesforce ?